# Calling method doesn't get the return value after a REST web-service call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest

I have a REST web-service (asp.net core 2.2 c#), and I'm calling it from a asp.net application (webform in VB.net).

The title isn't very accurate : I get a value from my web-service but the method before the one which call the web-method doesn't get the return value. So I have :

- method1 call method2
- method2 call method3
- method3 call webmethod
- method3 get the return value from webmethod
- method2 gets nothing
- method1 gets nothing neither

If I remove the call to the web-service from my method3 and directly return a new ApiReturn object to method2, method2 and method1 get the value as they should (actually method doesn't get the value

I am very new to REST webservice's world, so I have no clue... could you help me please ? This is my code :

Method 1 : BtnTestAnything_Click

```
Protected Sub BtnTestAnything_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim currentQuote As Quote = New Quote With {
        .NumberEpt = 13245,
        .Origin = "DM")

    LoemailApi.RunAsync(currentQuote).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
End Sub
```

Method2 : RunAsync  and Method3 : SendEmailToProviderAsync

```
Friend Class LoemailApi

Public Shared Async Function RunAsync(myQuote As Quote) As Task(Of ApiReturn)
            client.BaseAddress = New Uri("loemail_api_uri")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("loemail_api_media"))
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Clear()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(New StringWithQualityHeaderValue("loemail_api_charset"))

            Dim ret = Await SendEmailToProviderAsync(myQuote)

            ' I NEVER GET HERE EXCEPT WHEN I REMOVE THE CALL client.PostAsJsonAsync() TO WEB-METHOD IN SendEmailToProviderAsync()
                Console.WriteLine(ret)

            Return ret
End Function

Private Shared Async Function SendEmailToProviderAsync(ByVal quote As Quote) As Task(Of ApiReturn)

            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/providersSend", quote).ConfigureAwait(False)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

            Dim ret As ApiReturn = New ApiReturn()
            If (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) Then
                ret = Await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of ApiReturn)()
            End If

            ' HERE I HAVE A VALUE IN ret, ACCORDINGLY TO WHAT MY WEBSERVICE RESPOND
            Return ret   

End Function

End Class
```

Any comment on my code to help me improve it is welcome by the way.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I got it : I had the same issue while calling the web-method, and I resolved it by adding .ConfigureAwait(False) at the end of my call. So i dit the same to my SendEmailToProviderAsync call :

```
    ret = Await SendEmailToProviderAsync(myQuote).ConfigureAwait(False)
```

I assume my call isn't async anymore, but it's not an issue.